# php optional field code odd error

Tags: php

I am working on a php form, and i made two parts, required field and optional field. The following code works well apart from "email" field. I made email field to optional field but somehow it doesnt work as optional, it works like required field. 
if someone could paste the code and give it a try?

Many thanks for any suggestion.

```
<?php

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('phone');

$optional_fields = array('name','email');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'name' => 'Please enter your name, letters only',
    'phone' => 'Please enter a valid phone number',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
    //  if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

                // validate the phone number supplied
        if($field == 'phone') if(!validate_phone_number($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);

    }

        //starts here for optional validation   
    foreach($optional_fields as $field){
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

            // validate the name if supplied
    if($field == 'name') if(!validate_name($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);


    // validate the email address supplied
    if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);

    }   // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {

        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

//functions for validation different fields
function validate_name($phone = FALSE) {
    return (!preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', $phone))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function validate_email($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function validate_phone_number($phone = FALSE) {
    return (!preg_match('/\D/', $phone))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

?>



<?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?> 


  <form id="form" name="form"  method="post" action="">

      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input class="inter" type="text" name="name" id='name' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>"/><?php if(in_array('name', $validation)): ?><span class="phperror"><?php echo $error_messages['name']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
<p></p>


      <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input  type="text" name="phone" id='phone' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['phone'])? $_POST['phone'] : ''; ?>"/><?php if(in_array('phone', $validation)): ?><span class="phperror"><?php echo $error_messages['phone']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
<p></p>


      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id='email' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>"/><?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="phperror"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
<p></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Send"  />
  </form>


<?php else: ?>
<h2>Your message was sent</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line

```
// validate the email address supplied
if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
```

It's not checking for an empty $_POST['email']

```
// validate the email address supplied
if($field == 'email' && ! empty($_POST[$field])) if(!validate_email($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
```

Now it only fires the validation if $_POST['email'] is not empty

Comment: Dale, Many thanks for your help. :-) just another quick question, why name field works fine? Thanks again for your fast help

Comment: I'll take a look and see if I can figure that one out :)

Comment: It seems to always return true, I just tried adding this to the bottom of the code `<?php echo validate_name(''); echo validate_name('dale');?>` And I see `11` at the bottom, meaning that both validated.